# display header of gridview even when results are null ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and it works fine. But when I have no result the header disapears. Is there  a way to show it without code-behind?

I am using 3.5

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
DataTextField="Categorie" 
DataValueField="Cat_ID"
AppendDataBoundItems="True">

</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Goed %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_Cat]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: edited it ;) sorry forgot it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your sql query to return something in case of null.

```
if not exists (SELECT * FROM [tbl_Cat])
 select ' ' as Categorie,' ' as catid
 else
 select SELECT * FROM [tbl_Cat]
```

will work on all framework verson

another option is to override databind method where you can check the datatable. if the table row count is 0 you can manually insert blank values and then databind.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Below Property in gridview......

```
EmptyDataText="There are no crecords."
```

or set this template

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    No data found!
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Comment: This is only showing the text "There are no records." It wont show the header

Comment: setdatasource as string.empty ;

Answer (score 0):

Set the ShowHeaderWhenEmpty property:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use property in gridview

```
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
```

You code with changes

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
DataTextField="Categorie" 
DataValueField="Cat_ID"
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
AppendDataBoundItems="True">
```

for 3.5 follow this link 
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html

Comment: check this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For .net 3.5 use

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">No Data found..</td>
</tr>    
</table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

This would be the easiest way as far as I am concerned.